# WebBrowser - Windows Phone Application - Install/Uninstall Problems

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, browser, webbrowser-control

I making a WP8 app and i can't find any information about those 3 topics:

Protection against installing third-party browsers 
Supports "safe search" popular search engines 
Protection against uninstall applications

Answer (score 0):

You can control all of these from the workspace organisation options under settings --> organisation

but you must have the phone set to an organisations domain to be able to use these as it links in with windows server

Have a look here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=36831

Comment: OK - found it. But i could not find any samples :(